# dynamic function called on submit

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I want to validate a form but I want to have 9 different functions to validate the form. Which validation function gets used should be determined by a slider on the screen, or rather by the value in the span "range" which is controlled by the slider)

I can validate the form fine if I'm just using one function to do so with the below:

```
<script>
    function validateFormMethod1() {
        // do my validation stuff here
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="whatevermailscript.php"name="GuestInfo" onSubmit="return validateFormMethod1();">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
    <span>Guests</span>
    <span id="range">1</span>
    <input id="scaleSlider" type="range" value="1" min="1"  max="9" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value) ; showOrHide(this.value)"/>
```

But how can I add to this this so that if `range.value==2`  `validateFormMethod2` would get called instead of `validateFormMethod1`?

---

Update 3:

```
<script>


   function validateFormMethod0() {

    }  

    function validateFormMethod1() {
       window.alert("Method 1");
       return false;
    }

    function validateFormMethod2() {
        window.alert("Method 2");
        return false;
    }


    function validateFormMethod3() {
      window.alert("Method 3.");
      return false;
    }


    function validateFormMethod4() {
       window.alert("Method 4.");
       return true;
    }





    var validationFunctions = [
    validateFormMethod0,
   validateFormMethod1,
   validateFormMethod2,
   validateFormMethod3,
    validateFormMethod4

];
    function validateForm() {    

     var range = document.getElementById("range");

    validationFunctions[range.innerHTML]();
}


</script>
```

Still cant quite get this working as suggested but this serves my purpose:

```
 function validateForm()
{


 var range = document.getElementById("range");


   if (range.innerHTML == "1")
    {
        // do my validation stuff for case one here


    }


   if (range.innerHTML == "2")
    {
        // do my validation stuff for case two here


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array of functions.

```
var validationFunctions = [
   validateFormMethod1,
   validateFormMethod2,
   validateFormMethod3,
   ....
];

function validateForm() {        
    validationFunctions[range.value]();
}
```

Comment: Ive tried to implement your suggestion but im still doing something wrong, can you see what Im missing? I put an update above

Comment: You must declare your functions before using it. And `range.value` is just an example, it can't works like that. You must get the value of your slider with `document.getElementById("range").innerHTML`

Comment: I think I can get the value like this -var range = document.getElementById("range").innerHTML but what do you mean by "You must declare your functions before using it." ? I know what that would mean in objective C but not in Java.

Comment: Javascript != Java. We are talking about javascript here, there's no java. You can't use a function before the creation of the function. It's simple. So you must move your code for your validateFormMethod1, validateFormMethod2 (...), before the validationFunctions array.

Comment: Sorry, dont mean to offend. I rearranged the code but im still not understanding something.

Comment: I know you have no reason to help me here as I obviously have no idea what im doing. Ive managed to get everything else I need for this small project working except for this part. I would greatly apretiate it if you could tell me what it is im still doing wrong if you have the time. I could accomplish the same effect in objective C with a simple switch statement calling whatever method I want depending on the case. Whatver im still doing wrong here is causibg it to go straight to "whatevermailscript.php" whithout poping up any of the alerts.

Comment: if your html is still the same, you should replace `onSubmit="return validateFormMethod1();` by `onSubmit="return validateForm();`.

Comment: Sorry that was changed in the html I just only posted the Javascript in the updates as thats where the issue was. I finally got it to work and call the different functions with the above but the code blows out somewhere. The alerts pop up but the form action is still called even though it returns false right after the message pops up. Anyway I ended up just using several if statements within the one function which works for me in this case. I am accepting your answer though .....it was the right answer of course not your fault Im to daft to get it working the right way.

Comment: It's because `validateForm` must return `false` too.